# How to use a variable as a function name?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I'm trying to loop a function that will let users create a few custom posts, but I have a problem with the function name. Here is an example:

How can I write this:

```
function register_cpt_1_mdframework_price(){
```

… like this:

```
function $myvar(){
```

This is how I solved it, but it's neither nice nor clever – any better idea?

```
<?php
    $numcpost = of_get_option('how_many_custom_posts');
    do {
        switch ($numcpost){
            case 1:
                require_once MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpostloop1.php';
                break;
            case 2:
                require_once MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpostloop2.php';
                break;
            case 3:
                require_once MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpostloop3.php';
                break;
            case 4:
                require_once MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpostloop4.php';
                break;
            case 5:
                require_once MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpostloop5.php';
                break;
        };
    --$numcpost;
}while ($numcpost > 0);
```

#### File: cpostloop1.php

```
<?php
    $numcpost = 1;
    add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_'.$numcpost.'_mdframework_price', $numcpost );
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n'.$numcpost.'');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n'.$numcpost.'');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n'.$numcpost.'');
    $imgcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n'.$numcpost.'');
    function register_cpt_1_mdframework_price(){
        $labels = array( 
            'name' => _x( $plurcpost, 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New'.$singcpost.'', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit'.$singcpost.'', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'new_item' => _x( 'New'.$singcpost.'', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'view_item' => _x( 'View'.$singcpost.'', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'search_items' => _x( 'Search'.$plurcpost.'', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'menu_name' => _x( $singcpost, 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
        );
        $args = array( 
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'description' => $desccpost,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'high', 'middle', 'low', 'special', 'last_minute' ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post'
        );
    register_post_type( 'mdframework_custom_created_post_'.$numcpost.'', $args );
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing in that code doesn't seem much like the title or the initial description of the problem.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. And no matter what angle, it will always be a *pure PHP question*, that accidentally occurs within a WP environment, but is in no part WordPress specific. That being said, the `switch` can be avoided via `require_once( MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpostloop' . $numcpost . '.php' );`...

Comment: I am sorry, I tought that a structure like this: `function register_cpt_1_mdframework_price(){`
could be defined as a WordPress Problem...
@JohannesPille, you are true about the switch (actually is how I am doing in 'production' script) but I would like to understand how to use the variable $numcpost instead of the number in this function: `function register_cpt_1_mdframework_price(){`

Comment: So the solution is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213825/use-a-variable-to-define-a-php-function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$numcpost = of_get_option('how_many_custom_posts');

do {

    add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_mdframework_price', $numcpost );
    --$numcpost;

} while ( $numcpost > 0 );

function register_cpt_mdframework_price( $numcpost ) {

    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n'.$numcpost.'');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n'.$numcpost.'');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n'.$numcpost.'');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n'.$numcpost.'');

    $labels = array();
        // labels for $numcpost = 1
    $labels[1] = array(/*typo was here*/
            'name' => _x( $plurcpost, 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'mdframework_custom_created_post'.$numcpost.'' ),
    );

        // labels for $numcpost = 2
    $labels[2] = array(
        // ...
    );

    $args = array();

        // args for $numcpost = 1
    $args[1] = array(
            'labels' => $labels[1],
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'description' => $desccpost,    
    );

        // args for $numbercpost = 2
    $args[2] = array(
            'labels' => $labels[2]
        // ...
    );

    register_post_type( 'mdframework_custom_created_post_'.$numcpost, $args[$numcpost] );
}
```

Use multidimensional arrays. Simple, isn't it?